# OAuth2 client UI confusion

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security

So, I think I'm getting lost in the mass of approaches given I'm new to all of this but, I have a standalone Auth Server using basic auth for user credentials input.

I then have a very simple client app which is successfully redirect to `/oauth/authorize`, and then doing a subsequent calls to `/oauth/token` and `/oauth/check_token` as part of the flow. So I'm getting back the access token and it looks good.

The trouble is that I can't access any resources with in the UI app as its saying I'm not authenticated. I had added this to check state of things in a controller:

```
SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
```

The context is saying I'm not authenticated (but it does contain an OAuth2Authentication object the details holding the access token etc).

if I debug some more, I can see in OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter that is trying to get the bearer token from the request (BearerTokenExtractor) via the **Authorization** Headers but cant find it; should I be explicitly setting this after auth by the auth server?

What am I missing?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are not passing the token you received from the OAuth2 server in the headers for requests to the resource server; this is the mechanism by which the resource server can check if you are authorized and then set the proper security context.

You should set the following header for any request to the resource server:

```
Authorization: Bearer {your token}
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, many thanks for that.

I have 2 issues/question subsequent to that.

Firstly, to access resources in the same (client) app that i've marked as needing to be authenticated i'm getting 'Access is Denied'. i can see JSESSIONID and the XSRF token in dev tools in Chrome.

Secondly, to access remote resources, do i need to use an OAuth2RestTemplate, getting the bearer from the session?

Many Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0):

To round this all off, i fixed both issues.

1. remote resources; i used Zuul to proxy my requests which attaches the OAuth token for me.
2. local protected resources; rewrite of the http restrictions